# Pass and display JSON data from one page to another on click using local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have been trying to display JSON data from one page to another on click using local storage.

For example, a user clicks on an specific image of a book which then takes them to book.html where the image and the name of the book is shown (from the json file)

**FIGMA PROTOTYPE** - https://www.figma.com/proto/VAFgj0JQVX0YLt3WyZ12el/Untitled?node-id=5%3A5&scaling=min-zoom

script.js

```
const petsData = [{
  name: "Story Book",
  species: "Jean Lumier", //THIS IS THE JSON FILE
  photo: "a.jpg"
},
{
  name: "Barksalot",
  species: "Dog",
  href:"href.img,
  photo: "https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/images/dog-1.jpg"
},

];



function petTemplate(pet) {
  
return `
<div class ="image-grid">
   <div class="animal">
   
    <img class="pet-photo " src="${pet.photo}" >
   
      
       <div class="olay" onclick="location.href='${pet.href}';" style="cursor: pointer;">
       <div id="mydiv">
  
      <h2 class="pet-name">${pet.name}
      
      
      <h1 class="species">${pet.species}

      </div>
       <div></div></div>
      </div>
   </div>

  
`;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the JSON coming from?

Comment: What all are you using? Is this a Node app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set this up as a one page demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uzc5rj

Since your JSON does not have IDs, you can reference the position in the array in your book.html link. Like this:

```
<a href='book.html?book=1'><img of book /></a>
```

Then in book.html

```
<div id='book_details'></div>
   <script>
let bookData = localStorage.getItem('bookData');
 bookData = JSON.parse(bookData)

    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const bookPos = urlParams.get('book');
    
   
      let book = bookData[bookPos]
      let bookHtml =  `
    <div class ="book-html">
    <h1>${book.name}  </h1>
    <p>${book.species} </p>
    </div>
    `;
    
    document.getElementById('book_details').innerHTML = bookHtml;
 
  </script>
```

Comment: Sorry but im looking to use local storage for it

Comment: i used the exact same code that you sent but the page is just empty. Should the on click be like this? `<div class="olay" onclick="location.href='book.html?book=1';" style="cursor: pointer;">`

Comment: put some console.log() statements in your code to determine: are you getting the JSON data ok? are you getting the bookPos varable ok? At which point are things not working. And yes, your onclick looks fine

Comment: I looks like im getting the json data ok but im getting getTemplateFor is not defined error could just run the code that you posted and see that if it runs fine?

Comment: I simplified it a bit above, and made a one page demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-yx6yye?file=index.html

Comment: Thank you so much but im still getting the same error could you please check [https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-slwwex?file=index.html]

Comment: @LuisMaximus - Sorry, the project I started at stackblitz was a javascript app project so the links didn't work. I made a new basic html project. It works, you can review it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uzc5rj

Comment: @LuisMaximus - ok, all set. Your petTemplate function can recieve a second parameter through `map` which is the index. I use that in the link for each individual book, so that on book.html?book=INDEX, it can find the right JSON element from the index (using actual IDs is better practice, but array indexes will work for this demo) - https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uzc5rj

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help really appreciate it!